# How to create Apex trigger and apex class using Rest API?

Tags: python, salesforce

I am trying to integrate my app with salesforce and I am using Rest API using Python.
Following things I am implementing

1. Any user of Salesforce from any domain integrate with my app who is registered on my app.
2. Once user integrate app with salesforce I will get access token which I will use in Rest API call.
3. I want to create Apex trigger in salesforce on behalf of user which will call my app API.

I am stuck at point 3 because I am not finding documentation for creating Apex trigger using Salesforce Rest API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new [ApexTrigger](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_apextrigger.htm) using the Tooling API or update an existing one using [ApexTriggerMember](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_apextriggermember.htm).

There is an example of creating a Trigger using the REST API in [How do I use the Tooling API to create a new Apex Trigger?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9603/how-do-i-use-the-tooling-api-to-create-a-new-apex-trigger)

```
$ curl -H 'X-PrettyPrint: 1' -H 'Authorization: Bearer 00D...' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{ "Name" : "TestTrigger", \
          "TableEnumOrId" : "Opportunity",\
          "Body" : "trigger TestTrigger on Opportunity (after insert){}" }' \
    https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v27.0/sobjects/ApexTrigger
{
  "id" : "01qi0000000DKwyAAG",
  "success" : true,
  "errors" : [ ]
}
```